# How to correctly divide List<string>?

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

I have `List<string> {"", "1,5,4", "h", "5,8", "1"}`. I need to divide into 3 `List<int>`. This is my code:

```
var parseString = condition.Trim().Split(separator).ToList();
var numberSections = new List<string>();
var numberRow = new List<string>();
var numberCell = new List<string>();
foreach (var str in parseString) {
    if (int.TryParse(str.Substring(0, 1), out i) && numberSections.Count == 0) {
        numberSections.Add(str);
        parseString.Remove(str);
    }
    if (int.TryParse(str.Substring(0, 1), out i) && numberRow.Count == 0) {
        numberRow.Add(str);
        parseString.Remove(str);
    }
    if (int.TryParse(str.Substring(0, 1), out i) && numberCell.Count == 0) {
        numberCell.Add(str);
        parseString.Remove(str);
    }
}
```

But it do not working. How I can do it?

Comment: You cannot modify `parseString` while iterating it.

Comment: Also you only add item to each result list when these lists are empty. Why do you want to use 3 lists to store result instead of 3 string variable?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Can you give multiple examples for input and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a LINQ version for it

```
var result = list.Select(x => x.Split(",".ToCharArray(), 
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)) // now we have List<List<string>>
                .Select(x => x.Select(y =>
                {
                    int value;
                    var isInt = int.TryParse(y, out value);
                    return isInt ? value : (int?)null;
                })) // convert each element of inner list to null or its int values
                    // we have a List<List<int?>>
                .Where(x => x.Any() && x.All(y => y.HasValue)) // only select lists which contains only integers
                .ToList();
```